# How to freeze a row height or prevent line breaks in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My question is very similar to a [previous question here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/in-a-google-spreadsheet-how-can-i-force-a-row-to-be-a-certain-height), but I don't want the scroll bars.
When I paste a link in a cell it usually breaks the cell in multiple lines, increasing the row height. Even if I try to set the row height to 17 pixels, it keeps the same increased size. I don't need to visualize the whole link, I want only it to be clickable. Is there any solution for this?

One solution I found is to adjust the column width, but it creates a new problem: I don't want a very wide column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the toolbar option to switch off wrapped text:

[image: toolbar icon for wrap text]