# How do I eliminate extra line breaks in a Google Spreadsheets cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in which some cells have multiple carriage returns. I would like to eliminate all the extras, so that four carriage returns shrinks down to just one.

[image: Screenshot]

This question is similar to [How to freeze row height?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19535/how-to-freeze-a-row-height-or-prevent-line-breaks-in-google-spreadsheets), and [In a Google Spreadsheet, how can I force a row to be a certain height?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/in-a-google-spreadsheet-how-can-i-force-a-row-to-be-a-certain-height), but since there are new lines / carriage returns in the text, turning off text wrapping does not work.

Is there an easy formula to do this?

I can't do it with a simple find/replace because the length of the line breaks varies.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible at this time with Google Docs.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I did.

1. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search, and click the "..." button representing more options

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Typed \s+$ or \n in the find field
3. I left the replace field empty
4. Clicked "Search Using RegEx"
5. Clicked replace

I hope it works for you. Also, you can replace \n with any regex expression and it can be immensely helpful.

Comment: How can I do the inverse of this - replace a . with a .\n? When I run this search and replace, the literal text \n is inserted instead of a line break.

Answer (score 4):

the formula you would want is

```
=regexreplace("cell with your data","(\n)(\n{1,})","$1")
```

or

```
=regexreplace("cell with your data","(\r)(\r{1,})","$1")
```

the first one replaces new lines and the second on replaces carriage returns if needed.

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way would be to Find:

`&char(10) &char(10) &char(10) &char(10)`

and Replace with

`&char(10)`

with Also search within formulae ticked.