# Stop content from making cell two lines

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

In Excel if you have a long piece of text like a URL in a cell you can stop the cell from becoming a double-line cell and messing up the rest of your layout. It does this by just clipping the information that's in the cell.

[image: wrap cell]

Is there a way you can set this in Google Sheets?

Comment: See also: [In a Google Spreadsheet, how can I force a row to be a certain height?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deactivate line breaks in the toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are presently three options, in order of icons: `Overflow`, `Text wrapping` and `Clip`:

[image: WA43350 example]