# Reduce row height when cell includes carriage return

Tags: google-sheets

I use Google Sheets to store product information and often the product description is broken in to numerous paragraphs with carriage returns. In Google Sheets this increases the height of the row, and I'm unable to reduce it to keep the row height uniform throughout the spreadsheet:

[image: Google Sheets cell with a carriage return and text wrapping set to clip]

In Excel, both for desktop and online, a uniform height is achieved easily even if a carriage return is present in the cell:

[image: Excel online with a carriage return and text wrapping set to clip]

Is there a way to achieve the same fixed/reduced height in Google Sheets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The same paragraph has been pasted into both examples, but the Excel online example lets you reduce the height of the row and the rest of the text is hidden.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I suggest you too ask Google for this feature, as described here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/oEPLQhRPCgs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a Google Spreadsheet, how can I force a row to be a certain height?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/in-a-google-spreadsheet-how-can-i-force-a-row-to-be-a-certain-height)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a good answer for you directly.

But you are using the wrong tool.  It's hard to get a nut off a bolt using a screwdriver.

Workarounds:

A:  Other software.  This may be a case where you need a free form database, or at least a database that has a text object as one of the fields.  If you can afford it, try Filemaker Pro.  Be wary of flat-file solutions.  You will eventually need scripting, and relations.

B: Don't store the descriptions themselves in the spreadsheet, but instead put each description in a file.  In Sheets put a hyperlink to the file in the form file://path/to/your/product/AJ7723.txt.  (check that this syntax works before putting a bunch in place.)  If you do this cleverly, you may be able to use the same files on your web server an include them as the page is generated.

C: An ugly solution:  Replace carriage returns with some rare symbol such as solidus '|' This turns each description into a single run on paragraph, which will allow resizing.

Answer (score 1):

one solution would be to resize font on a minimum value. this would reduce row to 32px (while default is 21px)

also in a certain situation, this could be reduced even more by changing the direction of the text to vertical, however, this highly depends on the chosen font. for example this formula: **`="MMMM"&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"MMMM"`** includes 4 thick characters per row so by selecting a thin font like **Amatic SC**, **Wire One** or **Economica** and changing the direction of text from horizontal to vertical, there is possible to get 21px or even less simply by resizing font to 6px.

[image]

there is also one more solution - to merge such row with the row above or below - this way you don't need to change the font, size nor rotation (custom row height is magically unlocked):

[image]