# How To Create a Globally Accessible Apps Script for Docs and Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've been wanting to create a script that is accessible from any newly created Google Doc or Google Sheet. Is there any way to accomplish this?  For example, if I wanted to create a script that inserted the current date and time in a specific format into a Google Doc, I have to copy and paste that code into each new sheet. If I programmatically create a document, its also not there and must be copied and pasted in. Anyone ever accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way and many people already accomplished this (including me) by publishing the now called G Suite Add-ons. For details please read https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons

I already mentioned two of my add-ons here on Web Applications, Record Viewer and Spreadsheet Freezer.

Record Viewer

- [In Google Sheets: How do I merge a range of a row (the header) with the range of each column into a single cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119549/88163)
- [Viewing & editing data in Google Sheets using a form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132012/88163)

Spreadsheet Freezer

- [How do I install Spreadsheet Freezer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129211/88163)